# Debian [ Wheezy ] : Suricata : LibHTP outdated

Tags: debian, libraries, administration

While looking to test suricata from the Debian Wheezy repo I ran into an issue.

```
cat /var/log/suricata/suricata-start.log 

23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Info> - This is Suricata version 1.2.1 (rev 872e3cb)
23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Warning> - [ERRCODE: SC_WARN_OUTDATED_LIBHTP(200)] - libhtp < 0.2.7 detected. Keyword http_raw_header will not be able to inspect response headers.
23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Info> - CPUs/cores online: 1
23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Info> - NFQ running in standard ACCEPT/DROP mode
23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Info> - Using PCRE match-limit setting of: 3500
```

While I've download the libhtp source for 0.5.7 , installed a `.deb` archive from Debian Jessy ( 0.2.12 ) the lib keeps pointing at the old lib.

I've added `include /usr/local/lib/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
Ran and reran `ldconfig -v` , manually erased the cache `/etc/ld.co.cache` and reran what I could figure out to no avail.

Creating `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libhtp.conf` containing `/usr/local/lib/libhtp*` seemed to result in

```
ldconfig -p | grep libhtp
libhtp-0.5.7.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libhtp-0.5.7.so.1
libhtp-0.2.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhtp-0.2.so.1
```

What's going, what am I doing wrong? There is extremely little to find on this.

Answer (score 1):

Both are outdated. Suricata stable is at 1.4.6 and the libhtp version that should be used with it at 0.2.14, see http://suricata-ids.org/download/

libhtp 0.5.x is what we use in Suricata 2.0, which is currently in beta. It will not work with Suricata 1.4.6 due to API changes.

In general, using tools like Suricata from the distribution repositories is not a great idea. The versions are always quite far behind. I recommend installing from source.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 23/9/2013 -- 19:25:03 - <Warning> - [ERRCODE: SC_WARN_OUTDATED_LIBHTP(200)] - libhtp < 0.2.7 detected. Keyword http_raw_header will not be able to inspect response headers.
> ```

This is just a warning, not an error. Do you really require the `http_raw_header`? If not, just ignore it.

> installed a .deb archive from Debian Jessy ( 0.2.12 )

This is a bad idea. Even though it may be possible to install packages from a more recent Debian version without breaking anything, it does have repercussions.

For example, imagine that someone finds a critical security hole in `libhtp1`. Debian would then release new `libhtp1` packages that fix this security vulnerability, but it would release two packages, for example:

```
 Debian wheezy: libhtp1 (0.2.6-3)  (instead of 0.2.6-2)
 Debian jessy:  libhtp1 (0.2.12-2) (instead of 0.2.12-1)
```

Your system would see the `0.2.6-3` update because it is configured to pull the `wheezy` updates, but it already has `0.2.12-2` installed. `0.2.12-2` is higher (=newer) than `0.2.6-3`, so it won't install the update at all. You have now introduced a security vulnerability into your system that the Debian updater is unable to fix.

> While i've download the libhtp source for 0.5.7

Compiling and installing something from source is even worse. Don't do it.

> I've added include `/usr/local/lib/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Oh god, please stop before you've completely hosed your system :(

Comment: That must be the most educated yet pointless reply i ever saw.

Comment: Why is it pointless?

Comment: I was a bit (overly) agitated yesterday so pointless is a senseless use of words here. As i indicated i seen no error in any of your arguments.My aim though was, not to upset you, but to learn ;)  <br/>  

Sticking to DFHS is what i believe to achieve with using /usr/local/lib/libhtp/ for any of my unholy attempts.

I actually made it partially work. The new lib is in the output of `ldconfig -p` but the old one is still perferred. If you'd be willing to tell me on how to fix this without removing the libhtp1 package on which suricata depends ? I've removed the package i installed from Testing.

Comment: You still haven't clarified whether you actually need that `http_raw_header` keyword...

Comment: Do i really need to clarify that ? What if i continue thinking i don't need it and after many months i run into a time consuming issue which ... turns out to be http_raw_header is missing ? Less and less i understand the decisions made by package maintainers. Which obviously i'm not.

Comment: And, yes, i've looked it up. I hope i understand well what id does. As i cannot understand why this has been left out of the release goal for suricata in Debian. Is leaving it out not touching the ability to work with low-level diagnostics of http traffic ? Should it all be left to libhtp ? It would be more time-effiënt to have it than not to have, or am i expected to know libhtp by heart ?